# Selenium automation : Select JQuery Multiselect value

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

I have **JQuery multi-select drop-down** with check-boxes in it. I want to select it's check-box by passing parameters value/name. Please find image below which is a snapshot of the control on my page.I have tried this code but it didn't worked.

```
IWebElement ddlTitle = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ddlTitle"));
        SelectElement seddlTitle = new SelectElement(ddlTitle);
        ddlTitle.SelectByValue("479");
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post some code snippet? that you might've tried

Comment: Generally jQuery plugins like this don't use `select` elements and rather just style elements in a way to make it look like a dropdown. Please post the actual error, and the stack trace of what you get.